# tkinter 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack' (Still works?)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, tkinter, windows-xp

I'm fairly new to Python and have just started to play around with tkinter.
Running the below code I get an attribute error for `but1.pack()` (`NoneType` object has no attribute `pack`). But as far as I can tell this error is having no effect on the window's functionality, it is still `pack`ing the button. The window still appears and all the buttons behave as expected.

Searching I can see other people have had this error, but none of the answers given solved my problem. Hoping you can help.

The code:

```
import tkinter
import ctypes
lst=[]

user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
screensize = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)

def closewindow():
    window.destroy()
def btn1():
    lst.append("Button1")
def btn2():
    lst.append("Button2")

window = tkinter.Tk()

size = str(screensize[0])+'x'+str(screensize[1])
window.geometry(size)

but1 = tkinter.Button(window, text="Button1", command=btn1).grid(column = 1, row = 1)
but2 = tkinter.Button(window, text="Button2", command=btn2).grid(column = 2, row = 1)
ext = tkinter.Button(window, text="Stop", command=closewindow).grid(column = 3, row = 1)

but1.pack()
but2.pack()
ext.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

The callback;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\temp.py", line 59, in <module>
    but1.pack()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack'
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you get an error such as `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'X'`, that means you have a variable whose value is `None`, and you are trying to do `None.X()`. It doesn't matter if you're using tkinter or any other package. So, you have to ask yourself, "why does my variable have the value `None`?"

The problem is this line:

```
but1 = tkinter.Button(window, text="Button1", command=btn1).grid(column = 1, row = 1)
```

In python, when you do `foo=x(...).y(...)`, `foo` will always have the value of the last function called. In the case above, `but` will have the value returned by `.grid(column = 1, row = 1)`, and `grid` always returns `None`. Thus, `but1` is `None`, and thus you get `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack'".

So, the immediate fix is to move your call to `grid` to a separate line:

```
but1 = tkinter.Button(window, text="Button1", command=btn1)
but1.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
```

With that, the error will go away.

However, you have another problem. Calling `grid` and then later calling `pack` isn't going to do what you think it's going to do. You can only have one geometry manager in effect at a time for any given widget, and both `grid` and `pack` are geometry managers. If you do `but1.grid(...)` and later `but1.pack(...)`, any effect that calling `grid` had will be thrown away, as if you had never called `grid` in the first place.

You have to decide whether you want to use `grid`, or whether you want to use `pack`, and use only one or the other for all widgets in your root window.

Comment: If I comment out the pack() lines then the buttons don't appear in the frame. I'll do a bit more reading on the grid method I think. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this:

```
but1 = tkinter.Button(window, text="Button1", command=btn1).grid(column = 1, row = 1)
```

into this:

```
but1 = tkinter.Button(window, text="Button1", command=btn1)
but1.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
```

Chances are the `.grid()` method doesn't return a value.

Comment: Thanks, that appears to be the cause of the error. But now the .grid() method isn't registering. The buttons are in default locations (i.e. as if no grid() method was applied).

Comment: @I_do_python That's because `grid()` and `pack()` are mutually exclusive. Use one or the other.

Comment: Thanks Amber. Just sticking to grid and it's all working now.