# I have used grid manager in "root" window and i want to use pack manager in "toplevel" window. but it's showing error

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
def createmat_window():
    mat = Toplevel(cal)
    frame1 = Frame(mat,bg='red',width=100,height=100).pack()
    choices = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5'}
    pop = OptionMenu(frame1, opt1,*choices)
    pop.pack()
    opt1.set('1')



cal = Tk()                              # (ROOT_WINDOW )
cal.title("calculator")

opt1 = StringVar()
Matrix = Button(cal, padx=16, bd=8, fg="black", font=('arial', 15, 'bold'),
                    text="MAT", bg="honeydew3", command=createmat_window)
Matrix.grid(row=5, column=10)
```

it's giving me error _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid

but i have read that we can use different geometry managers in different windows irrespective of what other windows are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you do

```
frame1 = Frame(mat,bg='red',width=100,height=100).pack()
```

`frame1` is assigned the value returned by `pack()`, which is `None`. (Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19953464/3714930)).

Now when you use `frame1` as the master of the OptionMenu, this basically becomes

```
pop = OptionMenu(None, opt1,*choices)
```

Which makes the OptionMenu's master default to the main window, in this case `cal`, which already has a widget added with `grid()`.

You should be good when you change the creation of the frame to

```
frame1 = Frame(mat,bg='red',width=100,height=100)
frame1.pack()
```

Comment: code runs fine, when i correct my frame pack line but now the frame background doesn't show red color and only the "option menu". What's the reason behind??

Comment: Because the OptionMenu is exactly as large as the Frame it's in. If you want the Frame to be larger than the OptionMenu, you need to give additional arguments to the pack command like: `frame1.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)`. For more info about pack see [this effbot page](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm).